# Angular seed, where is the function variable coming from?

Tags: angularjs

There is an Angular [seed](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed) using Firebase and AngularFire on github form the Firebase team that I am trying to understand how works. The [login page](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed/blob/master/app/partials/login.html) looks like this:

```
  <form>
    <label>
        <span>email</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="email" />
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>password</span>
        <input type="password" ng-model="pass" />
    </label>
    <label ng-cloak ng-show="createMode">
        <span>confirm pass</span>
        <input type="password" ng-model="confirm" />
    </label>
    <button ng-click="login()" ng-hide="createMode">Log In</button>
    <button ng-click="createMode = true" ng-hide="createMode">Register</button>
    <button ng-cloak ng-show="createMode" ng-click="createAccount()">Create Account</button>
    <button ng-cloak ng-show="createMode" ng-click="createMode = false">Cancel</button>

    <p ng-show="err" class="error">{{err}}</p>
  </form>
```

And the [controller](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed/blob/master/app/js/controllers.js) for the login-function looks like this:

```
  $scope.login = function(cb) {
     $scope.err = null;
     if( !$scope.email ) {
        $scope.err = 'Please enter an email address';
     }
     else if( !$scope.pass ) {
        $scope.err = 'Please enter a password';
     }
     else {
        loginService.login($scope.email, $scope.pass, function(err, user) {
           $scope.err = err? err + '' : null;
           if( !err ) {
              cb && cb(user);
           }
        });
     }
```

The view calls the login function like this: `login()`, but in the controller the function definition starts like this `$scope.login = function(cb)` and then `cb` is used in the function. But the function is never called with any variable/object, so what is happening with `cb` here?

Comment: The parameter is not used when calling function from the template, but if you look at `$scope.createAccount` in the controller, it calls `$scope.login` with a callback

Comment: Aha, now I understand better :) And now I understand that in the line `cb & cb(user)` the point of the first cb is to verify that it exists. And `cb` is short for callback... Could you not make this an answer that I could accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter is not used when calling `login` function from the template, but if you look at `$scope.createAccount` function definition in the controller, it calls the same `$scope.login` function, but with defined callback parameter